# Python : Custom Attribute for Vertices

Tags: python, numpy

I want to store custom Vector attribute for each vertex (custom vertex positions). I want to get it through numpy as I have millions of vertices:

```
import bpy
import numpy

active_obj = bpy.context.active_object

active_obj.data.attributes.new(name='myAttribute', type='FLOAT_VECTOR', domain='POINT')

# set MAKES ERROR
test = numpy.empty(len(active_obj.data.vertices) * 3, dtype=numpy.float64)
active_obj.data.vertices.foreach_set('myAttribute', test)

# get MAKES ERROR
test2 = numpy.empty(len(active_obj.data.vertices) * 3, dtype=numpy.float64)
active_obj.data.vertices.foreach_get('myAttribute', test2)
```

I also found AttributeGroup.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AttributeGroup.html#bpy.types.AttributeGroup

Comment: The attributes.new is the "right" way, what errors did you get? You use it like `attributes['name'].data.foreach_get('vector', array)`. Other ways could be repurposing shape keys (if its a custom position).

Comment: (btw I think using a float64 array is pointless cause Blender only stores float32s)

Comment: Oh! You are right! I can create the attribute. But I cannot parse it with foreach_get/foreach_set
I modified my question

Comment: are you sure about float32? What if Blender Team will change it in future. May be I should leave float64?

Comment: Thank you a lot! All works fine!

Comment: Perfect candidate re https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/proposing-the-numpy-tag

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @scurest for answers in comments. Here is my working code now:

```
import bpy
import numpy

active_obj = bpy.context.active_object

active_obj.data.attributes.new(name='myAttribute', type='FLOAT_VECTOR', domain='POINT')

# set (you could also use numpy.empty)
test = numpy.zeros(len(active_obj.data.vertices) * 3, dtype=numpy.float32)
active_obj.data.attributes['myAttribute'].data.foreach_set('vector', test)

# get (you could also use numpy.empty)
test2 = numpy.zeros(len(active_obj.data.vertices) * 3, dtype=numpy.float32)
active_obj.data.attributes['myAttribute'].data.foreach_get('vector', test2)
```

Tested in Blender 2.92

Comment: One small thing, IMO would never set with `np.empty`  could use `np.zeros` here, but one assumes that is the default anyhow. Perhaps for  example sake get vert coords, manipulate and set to attribute.??

Comment: Thanks, I'll take into account. I tried np.zeros and np.empty with 12 million array of floats. No big difference.

Comment: Not a speed issue. (empty is quicker since it allocates space not value) hence  `np.empty` is likely full of rubbish values. No need to set with either since the default is already zero, and wouldn't bother to set with rubbish.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Is it possible to replace 0.0 values with zeros of np.array?

Comment: How can I set a float array attribute instead of a float-vector array? I set `FLOAT_VECTOR` to `FLOAT` but what to but into `vector` in `foreach_set`?

Comment: @Phann You ever figure this out?

Comment: @TheJeran: No, unfortunately not, my workaround is ``numpy.array(myFloatValues * 3)`` with ``FLOAT_VECTOR`` and ``vector``. See my full script based on the answer given here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241500/import-data-x-y-z-attributes-from-file-into-geometry-nodes/241870#241870

Comment: @Phann Oh shit, sorry I thought I edited my comment. I figured out the answer is 'value'

Comment: @TheJeran: Awesome. Thank you for that information! I'll improve my answer with a reference to your comment.